# Handling multiple checkbox values

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, backend

I am trying to develop an online study website using PHP for backend. My problem is that one teacher teaches in several faculties and I don't know how to insert his faculties into my DB and how to get it again from DB.

```
<?php /* */ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your DB. If you have one column for the faculties then you could seperate the entries by semicolon and later you can put them in an array with the explode function.
Something like this:

```
$faculties = explode(";",$varFromDB);
foreach($faculties as &$fac)
{
   echo $fac;
}
```

The better way is to have another table (in your DB) with all the faculties. In this entrys you will save all the primary keys from the teacher-table.

Maybe your given informations are not enough to understand your full question.